# How to show image date taken from phonegap capture camera

Tags: javascript, php, android, cordova

I develop web application using PHP and in this application there are function to show date taken, device name from image that uploaded manual (via web) to my server is successfully show date taken and device name. Then I create mobile application (android) using phonegap and there are function to capture image and save to my app directory. and when user save data to server i upload my capture photo that capture from phonegap camera feature to my server. But when I show in my web app date taken : unavailable ? and device name is availabe

my javascript code

```
function capturePhotoBatasAtas() {
    // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccessBatasAtas, onFail, { quality: 100,
    destinationType: destinationType1.FILE_URI });
}

function onPhotoDataSuccessBatasAtas(imageData) {
     ImagedataBatasatas = imageData;
     var smallImage1 = document.getElementById('BatasAtasPreview');
     smallImage1.style.display = 'block';
     smallImage1.src = imageData;
}

// save temp in array for many photo preview
var BatasAtasInfo={
        Keterangan:$('#txtKeteranganFotoBatasAtas').val(),
        val:ImagedataBatasatas
}

// save photo in my app folder before upload to server periodicly

for(var i=0;i<BatasAtasPhoto.length;i++){
        var object = BatasAtasPhoto[i]
        movePic(object.val,id+"BatasAtasPhoto"+i,function(entryData){
            if(entryData.isFile){
                BatasAtasPhoto[i].val = entryData.fullPath;
            }
        });
    }


function movePic(file,fileName,myCallBackUrl){
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(file, function(entry){
    //Callback function when the file system uri has been resolved
    var d = new Date();

    //new file name
    var newFileName = fileName + ".jpg";
    var myFolderApp = "sidato_app";
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSys) {
            //The folder is created if doesn't exist
            fileSys.root.getDirectory( myFolderApp,
                {create:true, exclusive: false},
                function(directory) {
                    entry.moveTo(directory, newFileName,  function(entry){
                        //Callback function when the file has been moved successfully - inserting the complete path
                        myCallBackUrl(entry)
                    }, resOnError);
                },
                resOnError);
        },
        resOnError);
}, resOnError);
}
```

Then there are My Php code for show date taken and device name

```
$path="../Model/photo/".$row['photo'];
$camera = cameraUsed($path);
echo '<div class="active item">';
if($_GET['act']==1){
    echo '<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete"   onclick=hapusFoto("'.$row['photoclimbupPK'].'") />';
}
echo '<img src="../Model/photo/'.$row['photo'].'"  />';
echo '<div class="carousel-caption">
<h4>Keterangan</h4>';
echo        '<p>';
echo "Camera Used: " . $camera['make'] . " " . $camera['model'] . "<br />";
echo "Date Taken: " . $camera['date'] . "<br />";
echo $row['Keterangan'].'</p></div></div>';
```

function camerea use in php

```
function cameraUsed($imagePath) {

// Check if the variable is set and if the file itself exists before continuing
if ((isset($imagePath)) and (file_exists($imagePath))) {

  // There are 2 arrays which contains the information we are after, so it's easier to state them both
  $exif_ifd0 = read_exif_data($imagePath ,'IFD0' ,0);       
  $exif_exif = read_exif_data($imagePath ,'EXIF' ,0);

  //error control
  $notFound = "Unavailable";

  // Make 
  if (@array_key_exists('Make', $exif_ifd0)) {
    $camMake = $exif_ifd0['Make'];
  } else { $camMake = $notFound; }

  // Model
  if (@array_key_exists('Model', $exif_ifd0)) {
    $camModel = $exif_ifd0['Model'];
  } else { $camModel = $notFound; }

  // Exposure
  if (@array_key_exists('ExposureTime', $exif_ifd0)) {
    $camExposure = $exif_ifd0['ExposureTime'];
  } else { $camExposure = $notFound; }

  // Aperture
  if (@array_key_exists('ApertureFNumber', $exif_ifd0['COMPUTED'])) {
    $camAperture = $exif_ifd0['COMPUTED']['ApertureFNumber'];
  } else { $camAperture = $notFound; }



  // Date
  if (@array_key_exists('DateTime', $exif_ifd0)) {
    $camDate = $exif_ifd0['DateTime'];
  } else { $camDate = $notFound; }

  // ISO
  if (@array_key_exists('ISOSpeedRatings',$exif_exif)) {
    $camIso = $exif_exif['ISOSpeedRatings'];
  } else { $camIso = $notFound; }

  $return = array();
  $return['make'] = $camMake;
  $return['model'] = $camModel;
  $return['exposure'] = $camExposure;
  $return['aperture'] = $camAperture;
  $return['date'] = $camDate;
  $return['iso'] = $camIso;
  return $return;

} else {
  return false; 
} 
}
```

where is date taken ??

any issue with date taken in capture photo use phonegap ??

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Code in server (php) or in phonegap (javascript) ?

Comment: both, prefreerably the javascript part

Comment: Oke wait ,because i going to office, after this i write both here ..

Comment: i have been edit my question with code, hopefully can make easier for any one to help me..